# Getting rid of optgroup and getting the real value when using an array in form_dropdown in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I'm having a problem with `form_dropdown` in `codeigniter`:

Here's my form:

```
ee()->load->helper('form');

        $sql = ee()->db->select('*')->from('exp_credit_tracker_credit_type')->get();

        $credit_type = array();

        foreach ($sql->result() as $row) {
            array_push($credit_type, $row->credit_name);
        }

        $data['credit_type'] = form_dropdown('credit_type', array($credit_type));
```

The output, for some reason is the following:

```
<select name="credit_type">
<optgroup label="0">
<option value="0" selected="selected">HOURS</option>
<option value="1">CREDITS</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

I don't need the `optgroup`.  Also, when I have a look at the value, I notice that they are indexed key-pair value. My problem is that I need to have the value `CREDIT` and `HOURS` so I can easily put them in my database later on.

What can I do? In a easy way, I don't want to loop through them again and again in order to match the key with the value.

Comment: You need to give it an array of `value => option label` so `array('HOURS' =>'HOURS')` you are giving it an array like `array(0 => 'HOURS')`.

Comment: Can you post your solution so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<optgroup>` tag is happening because of the array you are making. I believe the following change to the `foreach` will give the option values you want.

```
 foreach($sql->result() as $row) 
 {
     $credit_type[$row->credit_name]=$row->credit_name;
 }
```

Then you need to make a small change to the second argument of  `form_dropdown()`. Before you were putting the array `$credit_type` into another array. That's what caused the `<optgroup>` tag to appear.

```
 $data['credit_type'] = form_dropdown('credit_type', $credit_type);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give it an array of `value => option label` so `array('HOURS' =>'HOURS')`. You are giving it an array like `array(0 => 'HOURS')`